# Passing an object to .attr() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to pass an object literal to the .attr() method in jQuery to automate creating a DOM element.  The problem is when there is more than one attribute to set it fails.

```
var atts = {'type':'text', 'id':'#inputBox'};
createElem('<input></input>', '#divToAppendTo', atts);


function createElem(typeOfField, fldToAppendTo, atts){
    // this works when there is only one attribute to set, but fails when there is more than 1
    jQuery(typeOfField, atts).appendTo(fldToAppendTo);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try with `createElem('<input/>', '#divToAppendTo', atts);` but your code also working just fine http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/102/ and change `'id':'#inputBox'` to `'id':'inputBox'`

Comment: Probably you need `'inputBox'` instead of `'#inputBox'` .

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/usn5a/.

Comment: Are you experiencing this with IE only perhaps?

Comment: I think IE does not allow the "type" of an `<input>` element to be set after it's created. Try `$('<input type=whatever/>')` instead.

Comment: @Pointy but it works if you use `jQuery(html, attrs)` feature :) as in, passing the input type

Comment: @Jack hmm.  Well - ah, maybe the fact that the "id" is being set to something that's not an identifier?  Really shouldn't be a problem, even though I bet that it's not really intended.

Comment: @Pointy yeah that would have been my final guess =/

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your code and use this instead:

```
$( "<input>", {type:'text', id:'inputBox'} ).appendTo("#divAppendTo")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8cXF/

Note that for jQuery constructor all the following are equivalent and trigger the `document.createElement` optimization path:

```
"<input></input>"
"<input/></input>"
"<input/>"
"<input>"
 // Plus infinite different combinations of whitespace
```

Comment: I don't think IE will allow you to set the type of an `<input>` after it's created.

Comment: @Pointy why would you think so? It would be impossible to create input elements with a type then. Maybe you mean inputs that have been inserted into dom?

Comment: In old versions of IE, you have to do `$('<input type=text/>')` to create them. Now *maybe* jQuery can work around that, but I'm dubious. I'll check the source.

Comment: @Pointy `var a = document.createElement("input"); a.type = "text"` works, but if I change it to `"password"`, and then from `"password"` to `"text"` I get an error. I can however set the initial property just fine without any plumbing code. jQuery triggers an error when you attempt to set an input's type when it has `.parentNode`, it doesn't do any work-around.

Comment: Hmm.  Well that's the only thing that I could imagine causing a problem; the code in the OP looks fine, really.

Comment: @Pointy I wouldn't be surprised if his testing page has `<div id="#divAppendTo">` or other such mistakes.. http://jsfiddle.net/j8cXF/ (you made me doubt myself :))works fine in IE7

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `attr()` method in thread title , but aren't using it

Try:

```
 function createElem(typeOfField, fldToAppendTo, atts){
     // this works when there is only one attribute to set, but fails when there is more than 1
     jQuery(typeOfField).attr( atts).appendTo(fldToAppendTo);
}
```

Comment: He is using it in the second argument to jQuery constructor, which makes it call `.attr` internally with the object